# I want to transfer the data of a scoreboard to an entity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a value stored in a scoreboard objective, and I want to make that value the angle of rotation of an armor stand's arm. I used this command to store the value into the scoreboard:

```
/execute as @e[tag=test_1] store result score @s Test run data get entity @s Rotation.RightArm[0]
```

I tried things like:

```
/data modify storage score scoarboard merge from storage score scoarboard.objectives.Test
```

Comment: What is `u/e` and `u/s`? Do you mean `@e` and `@s`?

Comment: yes, it somehow converted into u/e and u/s

Answer (score 2):

The `/data` command is only used to transfer two NBT data storage.

To convert between scores and data, use `/execute store`:

```
execute store result entity @e[type=armor_stand,limit=1] Rotation.RightArm[0] int 1.0 run scoreboard players get ...
```

Comment: `1.0` isn't an `int`? Or is that part not an int?

Comment: @Penguin That is the mandatory `scale` parameter. It tells  Minecraft to multiply the received value by this amount before storing it in the final destination. If you don't want this to apply, you just enter `1.0` (multiply by 1). Technically you could just enter `1`, but I have a habit of entering the decimal portion if the argument is a decimal number.

Comment: Oh! Okay, I was just confused because it looked like it was for some reason a constant being casted or something. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I understood that <3